# Look up List of IDs in Multiple Workbooks and Return Values

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Master workbook with two sheets, one with data and another containing the IDs of different workbooks. I want to look up each record ID on the data tab in each Sheet listed on the second tab. When a record ID is found in one of the workbooks, values from columns J & K are copied and pasted to the data tab (in J&K as well) and moves on to the next ID. The different workbooks will contain multiple sheets so I only want to focus on a specific sheet in each of them (e.g. just Sep 2022). How can I modify the code below which appends the data from each sheet to merging specific columns to existing data? I would like this function to run onOpen if possible.

`

```
function data_Merger()
{
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const mergeSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data'); //Change sheet name
  const id_Sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet IDs'); //Change sheet name
  const IDs = id_Sheet.getRange('A1:A').getValues().flat().filter(r=>r); // Change to your column range which contains IDs
  var mergedData = []
  for(var i = 0 ; i < IDs.length ; i++)
  { 
       var ns = SpreadsheetApp.openById(IDs[i]).getSheetByName('Sep 22')
       var MRange = ns.getRange(2, 1, ns.getLastRow()-1, ns.getLastColumn()).getValues()   // Excluding Header Row
       for(var j = 0 ; j < MRange.length ; j++)
       {
         mergedData.push(MRange[j])
       }     
  }
  
  mergeSheet.getRange(2, 1, mergedData.length, mergedData[0].length).setValues(mergedData) // Pasting data in Master Sheet  
}
```

`

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the form of a sample spreadsheet. If possible, please include a sample of your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function data_Merger() {
  const mss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const msh = mss.getSheetByName('Data'); 
  const ish = mss.getSheetByName('Sheet IDs'); 
  const ivs = ish.getRange('A1:A' + ish.getLastRow()).getValues().flat(); 
  ivs.forEach((id,i) => {
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
    let sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sep 22');
    let vs = sh.getRange(2,10,sh.getLastRow() - 1,2).getValues();
    msh.getRange(msh.getLastRow() + 1 , 10 , vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
  });  
}
```

Comment: Hi @Cooper, thanks. I tried to adjust your code so that the data that's being copied is pasted from the second row in msh. There seems to be a problem where if the first sheet has 6 rows and the 2nd has 4, the 4 from the 2nd gets copied first and only the last 2 from the first gets copied to the main sheet. I've been trying to figure out for a few hours how to fix it on my own but no luck. Also, this code depends on the ordering of the existing data leaving room for mismatching. Can I get the copied records to paste by ID?

Comment: Without access to the real data it's a difficult thing to accomplish. Perhaps you should focus you question down to unique individual areas and provide us greater access to the data.